# How to use Task.WhenAny with ReadLineAsync to get data from any TcpClient

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

working my way through all that is async / await (coming from threadpools) and I've hit an interesting challenge.

I have a TCP Server running in a WPF application that accepts clients and stores them in a `List<>` like such:

```
private List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
while (running && clientCount <= maxClients)
{
    Client client = new Client(await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync());
    await client.WriteLineAsync("Connected to the Server!");
    clients.Add(client);
    clientCount++;
}
```

So what I want to do is iterate through the list of my Clients and if any data is received, I want to append it to a textbox. I realize **this may not be the best way** to achieve this, and I'm open to suggestions, but this is how I currently have it structured.

A button starts the loop and continuously calls and awaits `AllReadLineAsync()`

```
private async void btnStartReadLoopClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnStartReadLoop.IsEnabled = false;
    while(server.clientCount > 0)
    {
        string text = await server.AllReadLineAsync();
        txtOutputLog.AppendText("[client] " + text + "\n");
    }
}
```

which is this function:

```
public async Task<string> AllReadLineAsync()
{
    var tasklist = new List<Task<string>>();

    foreach (var client in clients)
        tasklist.Add(client.ReadLineAsync());

    while (tasklist.Count > 0)
    {
        Task<string> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasklist);
        if (finishedTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            return await finishedTask;

        tasklist.Remove(finishedTask);
    }

    return "Error: No task finished";
}
```

This function iterates through the list of clients and creates a `List<Tast<string>>` of all the `ReadLineAsync()` tasks.

At any given time, I may only have 1 or 2 clients actually sending data, so I can't `WhenAll()` and I've tried `WhenAny()` and `WaitAny()` without success.

**Note to future googlers:** `WaitAny()` is like `Wait()` and is blocking. Do not do this on a UI thread. Instead use `WhenAny()` and await it.

So my current implementation kind of works, but I can't figure out this bug where messages will build up from 1 client if the other clients don't send data.

**TL;DR:** Am I using `WhenAny()` correctly or is there a better way for me to await ReadLineAsync and pass the result to a textbox?

**EDIT:** Here's the behavior I'm seeing
I typed in this order: Left, Right, Left 2, Right 2, Left 3, Right 3 
and it appears as if some messages are being dropped?

[image]

**EDIT 2:** I found the source of the code snippet I copied on the MSDN blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/

This code snippet is meant specifically to iterate through a list of tasks ensuring they all are completed. I don't care if tasks are duplicated though so I need to modify the code to always check the entire tasklist instead of removing any tasks.

Comment: You're not removing the tasks that run to completion..?

Comment: Oh my god, cuz the return statement bypasses the remove statement... Wow. Let me give that a shot.

Comment: @stuartd Well that didn't *fix* the issue, but it does show me that sometimes 2 or more ReadLineAsync's are being grouped together. However it seems as if some messages are being delayed from 1 client until a message is sent in another client.

Comment: I think it might be because `tasklist` can be reduced to only 1 Task, at which point it functions as if it were only awaiting that task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I figured out where I was going wrong and why my previous code didn't work.

First off, let's talk about what this code does, and why it doesn't work:

```
public async Task<string> AllReadLineAsync()
{
    var tasklist = new List<Task<string>>();

    foreach (var client in clients)
        tasklist.Add(client.ReadLineAsync());

    while (tasklist.Count > 0)
    {
        Task<string> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasklist);
        if (finishedTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            return await finishedTask;

        tasklist.Remove(finishedTask);
    }

    return "Error: No task finished";
}
```

1) Creates a list of `await ReadLineAsync()`

2) While the size of that list is greater than 0, we wait for await any of the `ReadLineAsync` functions.

3) When we hit a Task that has finished, we return it's string, and exit the function

4) Any remaining `ReadLineAsync` functions that did not finish are still running, but we lost the reference to their instance.

5) This function loops, calling `AllReadAsync()` immediately after it finishes.

6) This causes us to try and access the StreamReady while it is still being awaited from step 4 - Thus throwing an excpetion.

---

### Handling Multiple TcpClients with an Async TCP Server

Because of the structure of this, I could not come up with a way to use `WhenAny()` in my application. Instead I added this function to my Client Class:

```
public async Task<string> CheckForDataAsync()
{
    if (!stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);
        return "";
    }

    return await reader.ReadLineAsync();
}
```

Instead of awaiting `ReadLineAsync()`, we instead access the NetworkStream from the TcpClient, and we check if there is data available, `if(!stream.DataAvailable)`, if there is not, we return early with an empty string, else we `await ReadLineAsync()` because we know we have incoming data, and we expect to receive the whole line.

We then replace the first function I talked about, `AllReadLineAsync()` With the following:

```
public async Task<string> AllReadLineAsync()
{
    string data = "", packet = "";
    foreach (var client in clients)
    {
        data = await client.CheckForDataAsync();

        if (data != string.Empty)
            packet += string.Format($"[client] {data}\n");   
    }

    return packet;
}
```

Which is even simpler than the previous way I was trying. This now iterates through all of our clients in a for loop, and calls the `CheckForDataAsync()` function on each client. Since this functions returns early instead of infinitely awaiting a full `ReadLineAsync()` it does not continue to run in the background after the `AllReadLineAysnc()` function ends.

After we finish looping through all of our clients, we take our string packet and return it to the UI context, where we can then add our data to a text box as such:

```
private async void RecvData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while(server.hasClient)
    {
        string text = await server.AllReadLineAsync();
        txtOutputLog.AppendText(text);
    }
}
```

And that's it. That's how I'm handling multiple TcpClients from within a WPF application.

Comment: why not return immediately when no data is available in the socket? you can use Task.FromResult() instead. also - this way, aren't your checking one by one and not in parral?

Comment: When I was returning immediately I was locking up the UI so adding the Delay prevented that. I hadn't seen `Task.FromResult()` yet so I'll have to look into that! And I'm not checking in parallel yet because I was trying to keep it simple and working before complicating the code. If you would like to create a pseudo code example, that would be helpful! Else I'll just read up some more and post another answer with that! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> it appears as if some messages are being dropped?

Yes. Because asynchronous work is *started* when you call their method (e.g., `ReadLineAsync`). When one of them completes (`Task.WhenAny`), your code abandons the other tasks. But they keep running - they're still reading from their sockets, and whatever they read is just going to be thrown away.

AFAIK, the behavior is undefined when you start reading from the same socket *again* - it's possible it may read what's next, or it's possible it may be queued. I do know that you're not supposed to do issue multiple reads from a socket (or any stream) simultaneously.

Sockets are not a perfect match to `async`, because they *can* send data at any time. You should use Rx or events instead. It's possible to make `async` work but it's extremely complex.

Comment: First off, your site has been a tremendous help to me! Thank you for that.
Now I actually figured out how to do this without `WhenAny()` or accessing the streamreader. Instead I make use of TcpClient's NetworkStream and simply check `stream.DataAvailable` and return early if there is no data. Much simpler and cleaner. As far as the behavior go, it actually throws an exception, ONLY if you didn't fire and forget the task. I'll post an answer with how I implemented it. Thanks for the advice and the help!